# Flutter, Update Map Value from entries

Tags: flutter, hashmap

I created a single map for the whole app and I'm accessing data based on various index.
I need to know how to update a value, a specific value.

Assuming the Map map, here the code:

```
map.entries
        .map((e) => e.value)
        .where((element) => element.bottomTabIndex == Variables.bottomTabIndex)
        .toList()
        .where((element) => element.leftTabIndex == Variables.leftTabIndex)
        .toList()
        .where((element) =>
            dateToString(element.date) == dateToString(Variables.date)).
```

By this way I have not the option .update() at the end of the code. Not too also the .asMap() function.

I imagine that is because I'm working with the 'entries' function of the Map.

There is a way to update a Map after filtered like my example?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way: to get the key!

```
static void addIngredientWeight(Ingredient ingredient, double? weight) {
    var mapKey = Variables.map.keys
        .firstWhere((element) => Variables.map[element] == ingredient);     
      ingredient.weight = weight;
      Variables.map.update(mapKey, (value) => ingredient);
  }
```

There is also a way to get specific values, eg:

```
.firstWhere((element) => Variables.map[element].anyValueIWantToCompare
```